# Different set of results returned for same search request on same datasets

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have observed that different set of responses are obtained on same query and same datasets while doing search. Is this expected or am I missing anything?

Service and request details:

```
Subscription: 857c2508-0288-42b1-ba14-3d49188259b6
ResourceGroupName: rss-dev-wus2-search-rg
ServiceName: "relevance-search-dev-westus2"
IndexName: idx-vreb9d099kr6wd0vdid7gdlphlwtqynv7par4w56yi1b96xyujbn5l4yziaq93kh68wwhb64wwol3f630xl7zlt22h6y23lt
ClientUsed: Microsoft.Azure.Search.ISearchIndexClient
Version: Version=10.1.0.0
RequestUri: https://relevance-search-dev-westus2.search.windows.net/indexes/idx-vreb9d099kr6wd0vdid7gdlphlwtqynv7par4w56yi1b96xyujbn5l4yziaq93kh68wwhb64wwol3f630xl7zlt22h6y23lt/docs?api-version=2020-06-30&%24filter=g%20eq%201024&%24select=b&%24top=60&%24skip=0&search=Xbox
QueryString: $filter=g eq 1024&$select=b&$top=60&$skip=0&search=Xbox
```

Service Request IDs for which different results are obtained:

> 0e01f6aa-f743-4416-9a34-fd92578dbfee

> f7a2c9d3-6254-4aab-90c9-726732e48c00

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your search service is setup with multiple replicas. Index statistics can be slightly out of sync between replicas at any given time, which means that relevance scoring for the same document can change slightly from one request to the other if a difference replica node is serving the results. You can use the optional "sessionId" parameter in your search requests for cases where score consistency is required.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#sessionidstring-optional

As long as the same sessionId is used in successive requests, best-effort will be made to target the same replica node.